# Flash Motion-tween fails over cross-domain loading

Tags: actionscript-3

This is a weird one. I believe it could be a bug in flash.
Hopefully I'll get an answer as there seems to be less people using flash nowadays ;-)

I've got basically two SWFs:

1. Main -> The loader
2. Animation -> The loaded, with 3D motion tweens (using flash pro)

When the **animation** is loaded on the same server, the animation runs fine.

*BUT*, when the **animation** is loaded on an external location (using allowDomains), the motion tweens do not work and the clips loop indefinitely.

No errors are thrown from the debugger.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Note: I have no choice but to load the file externally, I have a size limit of 80K for the initial file and files cannot be stored on the same server for no reason at all

Comment: `using allowDomains` do you use `Security.allowDomain` on both applications: main and loaded?

Comment: yes I do. Without allowDomains, nothing works. Let me add that the other elements in the loaded animations play… except for Motion tweens with 3D.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security limitation of Flash Player. By default, it prevents loading binary files from another domain. This is not specific to 3D motions tweens.

The workaround consists in adding a crossdomain.xml file **at the root** of the second web server (the one from which you want to download the animation.

A basic crossdomain file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- http://www.osmf.org/crossdomain.xml -->
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can change the line `<allow-access-from domain="*" />` to `<allow-access-from domain="<THE DOMAIN OF THE LOADER SERVER>" />` to ensure only your loader will be able to use your animation.

Comment: I belive you haven't read my post correctly. I've already set allow-access. without it, nothing works. In this case, ONLY the motion tweens fail to play (and ONLY when loaded as external file)

Comment: I thought you were talking of http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html, no crossdomain.xml. Do your animations include images from another domain?